# Show that $\lim\limits_{x\longrightarrow0}\frac{1}{x^2}$ does not exist on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Show that $\lim\limits_{x\longrightarrow0}\frac{1}{x^2}$ does not exist on $\mathbb{R}$

**My attempt:**

In order for the limit to exist, Cauchys convergence criterium has to hold:

$\forall \epsilon > 0\,\,\, \exists \delta > 0:\forall x,y \in \dot{\mathcal{U}}_\delta(0)\cap \mathbb{R} \Longrightarrow |\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}|<\epsilon$

$|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}|<\epsilon \Longleftrightarrow |\frac{y^2-x^2}{(xy)^2}|<\epsilon \Longleftrightarrow |y-x||y+x|<\epsilon(xy)^2$

Now since $x,y \in \dot{\mathcal{U}}_\delta(0)\cap \mathbb{R}$ we could choose $d(x,y)=|y-x|=\frac{\delta}{2}$

This would mean:

$\frac{\delta}{2}|y+x|<\epsilon(xy)^2$

Now let $x \longrightarrow 0$

To keep the distance $d(x,y)=\frac{\delta}{2}$ we now set $y:=\frac{\delta}{2}$

$\frac{\delta}{2}|\frac{\delta}{2}+0|<\epsilon(0*\frac{\delta}{2})^2$

This would require $\delta<0$ in order for our inequation to hold for any $\epsilon > 0$

Which is a contradiction.

It would be very helpful if someone could give me some feedback :)

Comment: hint: show, that limit is $+\infty$

Comment: Oh I cannot work with the left and right limit to show that left limit $\ne$ right limit, since im not there in my book.. i have to work with cauchys definition.. Is my attempt not working?

Comment: Try to take negation of Cauchy.

Comment: Okey but just to get that clear, what i did, is simply wrong, isnt it?

Comment: It seems little complicate. Let's take $|\frac{y^2-x^2}{(xy)^2}|<\epsilon$. If here you will let $x \rightarrow 0$, then already is impossible to keep inequality. Or may be I understand your idea wrongly. ?

Comment: yes.. hmm I really tried hard to express the inequality in terms of $\delta$, and show either the cauchy criterium doesnt hold or the negation does hold, but somehow I needed x or y to approach zero to get what I needed.. argh how can I express it in terms of $\delta$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy Criterium for function $f$ in point $a$:
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x \in \left| x- a \right|< \delta, \space  \forall y \in \left| y- a \right|< \delta, \space \left|f(x) - f(y) \right|< \epsilon$$

negation:

$$\exists \epsilon >0, \forall \delta >0, \exists x \in \left| x- a \right|< \delta, \space  \exists y \in \left| y- a \right|< \delta, \space \left|f(x) - f(y) \right|\geqslant \epsilon$$

So, really, $x$ and $y$ are functions of $\delta$. It is enough to find sequences $\left\lbrace x_n\right\rbrace \rightarrow a$ and $ \left\lbrace y_n\right\rbrace \rightarrow a$, for which held $\left|f(x_n) - f(y_n) \right|\geqslant \epsilon$.

Now let's take $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}}$. Both $\rightarrow 0$. But then we have

$$\left|f(x_n) - f(y_n) \right| = \left|  n- (n+1) \right| = 1$$

So we find sequences for $\epsilon = 1$.

Comment: Hey @zkutch could you look over my answer I put into this discussion? It was an example to make sure I understood your answer completly :)

Comment: Yes, it's correct, if you mean point $a=0$. For complete confidence try some function in point $a \ne 0$. For example $\frac{1}{x-5}$.

Comment: $x_n=\frac{1}{n}+5$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+5$ both approach 5, than $|\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+5-5}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n+1}+5-5}|=|n-n-1|=1$ So we found two sequences for which we finde a epsilon which satisfies the negated cauchy criterion

Comment: In general, If I work with any $\epsilon \delta$-criterium, and I want to negate the statement, can I always take a sequence to find a counter example?

Comment: It's correct for first comment above and yes for question in second comment: why? because by such sequence we always satisfy $\forall \delta >0 $ condition. So, happy hunting/analysis.

Comment: thank you :)!!!

Answer (score 1):

We can just proof that 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}=+\infty
$$

By definition this is equivalent to show that
$$
\forall M > 0 \  \exists \ \delta > 0 : \forall x \in (-\delta,\delta)\quad  \text{ we have} \quad \frac{1}{x^2} > M
$$

Let fix $M >0$, we are looking for the $\delta$, hence
$$
\frac{1}{x^2} > M \iff x^2 < \frac{1}{M} \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt M} < x < \frac{1}{\sqrt M}
$$

So we can just choose $\delta = \frac{1}{\sqrt M}$.

Comment: okey yeah this makes total sense :) But is my approach completly wrong?

Comment: Isnt the Cauchy Criterium negation: $\exists \epsilon >0 \forall \delta >0 : \exists x,y \in \dot{\mathcal{U}}_\delta(0) \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| \ge \epsilon$ So we need to show it holds for all $\delta$

Comment: Wrote it below/above - it jumps so, that hard it's hard to point.

Answer (score 0):

Okey so if I want to show the same for $f(x)=\ln(x)$

I choose $(x_n) $ with $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$

and $(y_n) $ with $y_n=\frac{1}{2n}$,

$y_n\longrightarrow0$ and $x_n\longrightarrow0$

Now $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=|\ln(\frac{1}{n})-\ln(\frac{1}{2n})|=|\ln(\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{2n}})|=|\ln(\frac{2n}{n})|=|\ln(2)|$

so we find two sequences we can use to show the negation of the cauchy criterium holds for $\epsilon=\ln(2)$

If this is correct, you did me an amazing favour because you also opend some eyes in terms of analysis in general :)